# Allow Html Attribute Not Found [AllowHtml]

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, attributes

Can anyone tell me what I need to include besides System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations to get [AllowHtml] to be recognized?  When I add the attribute to a property it tells me the following compiler error:

> *"The type or namespace name 'AllowHtml' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"*

I need to allow html to my field and cannot continue until I get this working.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks...

Answer (score 20, accepted):

As far as I can tell, [AllowHtml] belongs to the System.Web.Mvc namespace.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.allowhtmlattribute(v=vs.98).aspx

Comment: You are a life saver!  Thanks so much!  I googled but did not try MSDN.  I forgot the good ole Microsoft Documentation :-)

Answer (score 5):

I had this same issue and took me a while to realise that I was referencing system.web.mvc v2 not v4, so make sure you check the version.

FYI, I had my models stored in a separate project